# Pruebas unitarias con QUnit

Tags: javascript, html5, pruebas-unitarias

Buenas Tardes,

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Intel XDK y utilizo funciones javascript en ficheros html.
Necesito realizar pruebas unitarias para la verificación de que funcionan correctamente las funciones.Estoy utilizando Qunit para ello y me da error en la prueba a la hora de buscar un usuario dentro de la base de datos.
Cree un fichero test y en el fichero html introduje las cabeceras script de QUnit pero no entiendo porque me da error a la hora de buscar un paciente.Pego el código de ambos.

```
   ***test.js***
QUnit.test("Mi Primera Prueba",function (assert) {
    assert.ok(buscarpacient("121"),"Satisfactorio");
});

QUnit.test( "hello test", function( ) {
  ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});

***buscarpacient.html***

function buscarpacient() {

        var active = dataBase.result;
        var data = active.transaction(["pacientes"],"readwrite");
        var object = data.objectStore("pacientes");    

        // primero buscamos el registro a partir del dni
        var index = object.index("by_dni");
        var request = index.get(calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value));//calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value)

         request.onerror = function(event) {
         alert("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");
         };
        // cuando se encuentre el registro, lo borramos
        request.onsuccess = function () {
        if(request.result == undefined)
        {
         alert('No existe ese paciente');   
        }else{
        var result = request.result;
        alert("There the patient and has the ID: " + result.id);
        passdata(document.querySelector("#dni1").value);
        //anterior antes de md5 passdata(result.dni);

        //object.delete(result.id);
          }
        };
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar con las pruebas unitarias?

Comment: Y en qué momento `buscarPaciente` entrega como respuesta `true` o `Satisfactorio`?